# How to setstate an item in the list

Tags: reactjs

i have a list and want only to setState the 2nd item on an eventhandler. I'm trying to set using `lists: this.state.lists[1]` but it throws an error saying `this.state.lists.map is not a function`. What is the right way to setstate an item from list? here is what i'm doing:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lists: []
    };
    this.buttonAHandler = this.buttonAHandler.bind(this);
  }


 componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.com')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ lists: data }));
 }



  buttonAHandler(e) {
    this.setState({
    lists: this.state.lists[1]
   })
  }
```

in my render return i'm binding the handler like this.:

```
render(){
    return (
      <div> 

     <button onClick={this.buttonAHandler.bind(this)} >see pets</button>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "want only to setState the 2nd item"? Do you want to remove all the items in the array except the 2nd element, or do you want to change something in the 2nd element?

Comment: Yes I have list of items and when the button is clicked I want to set state only the 2nd element.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean. Could you elaborate more on how you want to "set state only the 2nd element"?

Comment: @Deke That didn't clarify what you are trying to do. Do you want `lists` to remain an array, but update a single item in the array, or do you want `lists` to become the item in the array and throw away the rest of the items?

Comment: Lets say the this.state.lists is  [{a:"abc"},{b:"def"}], when button is clicked, I want to set the state to the second item which is `{b:"def"}`.

Comment: @Deke So after you make the change, `console.log(this.state.lists)` would return `{b: "def"}`, correct?

Comment: Supposed to but I'm getting an error :(

Comment: @Deke You are likely using code somewhere else in your application that assumes that `this.state.lists` is an array, then. Based on your error message, I would assume that `this.state.lists.map()` is the culprit. You're changing it from an array to an object, hence why `.map()` throws an error

Comment: Matheus is correct. I was not using an array like this: [this.state.lists[1]]. Thank you Tholle, mhodges

Comment: So your output **really** should be `[{b: "def"}]` - big difference from what you said above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're receiving an error because, after the click, the `lists` state changes from an `Array` to a `Object`(the index 1 of the array). So, if you want to still using the `map()` method, change you handler to:

```
buttonAHandler(e) {
   this.setState({
       lists: [this.state.lists[1]]
   })
}
```

Then, the new `lists` state will be an `Array` with just the element that you want.

Comment: @mhodges, probably the `map()` is being used to render the data. Then, after the change from `Array` to `Òbject`, it isn't possible anymore.

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I was thinking. Looks like OP was just confused in the comments above. Your solution is what they were looking for - deleting my previous comment as it is now obsolete